# Could not link CPLEX library in R

Tags: r, terminal, linker, installation, cplex

I am trying to install `Rcplex` in `R` on a macbook and I'm following the instruction at this link http://jrzubizarreta.com/INSTALL.

On terminal, in the folder where I unzipped `Rcplex` (`Users/Downloads`), I typed

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC' 
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include 
PKG_LIBS='-l/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic 
-lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'" Rcplex
```

The error I receive reads:

configure: error: Could not link CPLEX library using -
   l/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -
   lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit
   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’

The `makefile` with the info on `CFLAGS` and `CLNFLAGS` and the `config.log` file from the folder where I installed `Rcplex`are attached below.

I'm not experienced at installing sw from terminal, but I really need this sw to work. Anyone understands where the problem is? Thank you.

PS: I have already posted a similar question in the past (at [error: C compiler cannot create executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300644/error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables/56304866?noredirect=1#comment99232970_56304866)) but I couldn't make this work despite the previous post was very helpful.

```
********************* START MAKEFILE  ***********************************
SYSTEM     = x86-64_osx
LIBFORMAT  = static_pic

#------------------------------------------------------------
#
# When you adapt this makefile to compile your CPLEX programs
# please copy this makefile and set CPLEXDIR and CONCERTDIR to
# the directories where CPLEX and CONCERT are installed.
#
#------------------------------------------------------------

CPLEXDIR      = ../../..
CONCERTDIR    = ../../../../concert

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler selection 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

CCC = clang++ -O0
CC  = clang -O0
JAVAC = javac 

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler options 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

CCOPT = -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -stdlib=libc++
COPT  = -m64 -fPIC
JOPT  = -classpath $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/cplex.jar -O

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link options and libraries
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

CPLEXBINDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/bin/$(BINDIST)
CPLEXJARDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/cplex.jar
CPLEXLIBDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)
CONCERTLIBDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)

# For dynamic linking
CPLEXBINDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/bin/$(SYSTEM)
CPLEXLIB      = cplex$(dynamic:yes=1290)
run           = $(dynamic:yes=DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(CPLEXBINDIR))

CCLNDIRS  = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -L$(CONCERTLIBDIR) $(dynamic:yes=-L$(CPLEXBINDIR))
CLNDIRS   = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) $(dynamic:yes=-L$(CPLEXBINDIR))
CCLNFLAGS = -lconcert -lilocplex -l$(CPLEXLIB) -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit -stdlib=libc++
CLNFLAGS  = -l$(CPLEXLIB) -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit
JAVA      = java  -d64 -Djava.library.path=$(CPLEXDIR)/bin/x86-64_osx -classpath $(CPLEXJARDIR):


all:
    make all_c
    make all_cpp
    make all_java

execute: all
    make execute_c
    make execute_cpp
    make execute_java
CONCERTINCDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/include
CPLEXINCDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/include

EXDIR         = $(CPLEXDIR)/examples
EXINC         = $(EXDIR)/include
EXDATA        = $(EXDIR)/data
EXSRCC        = $(EXDIR)/src/c
EXSRCCX       = $(EXDIR)/src/c_x
EXSRCCPP      = $(EXDIR)/src/cpp
EXSRCJAVA     = $(EXDIR)/src/java

CFLAGS  = $(COPT)  -I$(CPLEXINCDIR)

********************* END MAKEFILE  *************************************


********************* START CONFIG.LOG **********************************

Removed because of space limit

********************* END CONFIG.LOG  ***********************************
```

@rkersh correctly pointed out that the `-l` should actually be `-L`. Unfortunately, the code still gives error. I attached the `config.log` from running:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC' PKG_CPPFLAGS=-
I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include PKG_LIBS='-
L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -
lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'" Rcplex


********************* START CONFIG.LOG WITH `-L`  ***********************

This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Rcplex configure 0.3.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure PKG_CFLAGS=-m64 -fPIC PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include PKG_LIBS=-L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Andrews###
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 16.7.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 365 tasks, 1784 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 2.23, Mach factor: 1.76
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/andrews/anaconda/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
PATH: /Users/andrews/anaconda/bin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /Library/TeX/texbin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1631: checking for gcc
configure:1657: result: clang
configure:1901: checking for C compiler version
configure:1904: clang --version </dev/null >&5
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
configure:1907: $? = 0
configure:1909: clang -v </dev/null >&5
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
configure:1912: $? = 0
configure:1914: clang -V </dev/null >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:1917: $? = 1
configure:1940: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:1943: clang -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:1946: $? = 0
configure:1992: result: a.out
configure:1997: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2003: ./a.out
configure:2006: $? = 0
configure:2023: result: yes
configure:2030: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2032: result: no
configure:2035: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2037: clang -o conftest -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2040: $? = 0
configure:2065: result: 
configure:2071: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2092: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2095: $? = 0
configure:2117: result: o
configure:2121: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2145: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2151: $? = 0
configure:2155: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2158: $? = 0
configure:2161: test -s conftest.o
configure:2164: $? = 0
configure:2177: result: yes
configure:2183: checking whether clang accepts -g
configure:2204: clang -c -g -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2210: $? = 0
configure:2214: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2217: $? = 0
configure:2220: test -s conftest.o
configure:2223: $? = 0
configure:2234: result: yes
configure:2251: checking for clang option to accept ANSI C
configure:2321: clang  -c -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2327: $? = 0
configure:2331: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2334: $? = 0
configure:2337: test -s conftest.o
configure:2340: $? = 0
configure:2358: result: none needed
configure:2376: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:2:3: error: unknown type name 'choke'
  choke me
  ^
conftest.c:2:11: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
  choke me
          ^
          ;
2 errors generated.
configure:2382: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| #ifndef __cplusplus
|   choke me
| #endif
configure:2520: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:2638: result: clang -E
configure:2662: clang -E -I/usr/local/include conftest.c
configure:2668: $? = 0
configure:2700: clang -E -I/usr/local/include conftest.c
conftest.c:9:10: fatal error: 'ac_nonexistent.h' file not found
#include <ac_nonexistent.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
configure:2706: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Rcplex"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rcplex"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Rcplex 0.3.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:2756: checking for egrep
configure:2766: result: grep -E
configure:2771: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:2796: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2802: $? = 0
configure:2806: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2809: $? = 0
configure:2812: test -s conftest.o
configure:2815: $? = 0
configure:2904: clang -o conftest -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include  conftest.c -L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit >&5
conftest.c:26:7: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type 'void (int) __attribute__((noreturn))'
      exit(2);
      ^
conftest.c:26:7: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'exit'
1 warning generated.
configure:2907: $? = 0
configure:2909: ./conftest
configure:2912: $? = 0
configure:2927: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for sys/types.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for stdlib.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for string.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for memory.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for strings.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for inttypes.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for stdint.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:2951: checking for unistd.h
configure:2967: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2973: $? = 0
configure:2977: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2980: $? = 0
configure:2983: test -s conftest.o
configure:2986: $? = 0
configure:2997: result: yes
configure:3019: checking ilcplex/cplex.h usability
configure:3031: clang -c -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c >&5
configure:3037: $? = 0
configure:3041: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:3044: $? = 0
configure:3047: test -s conftest.o
configure:3050: $? = 0
configure:3060: result: yes
configure:3064: checking ilcplex/cplex.h presence
configure:3074: clang -E -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include conftest.c
configure:3080: $? = 0
configure:3100: result: yes
configure:3135: checking for ilcplex/cplex.h
configure:3142: result: yes
configure:3154: checking for library containing CPXversion
configure:3184: clang -o conftest -Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include  conftest.c -L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit >&5
configure:3190: $? = 0
configure:3194: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:3197: $? = 0
configure:3200: test -s conftest
configure:3203: $? = 0
configure:3273: result: none required
configure:3415: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by Rcplex config.status 0.3.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on Andrews###

config.status:638: creating src/Makevars

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_exeext=
ac_cv_header_ilcplex_cplex_h=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_prog_CPP='clang -E'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=clang
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_stdc=
ac_cv_prog_egrep='grep -E'
ac_cv_search_CPXversion='none required'

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AWK=''
CC='clang'
CFLAGS='-Wall -g -O2 -m64 -fPIC'
CPLEX_BIN=''
CPP='clang -E'
CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include -I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include'
DEFS='-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Rcplex\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"rcplex\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.3.2\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Rcplex\ 0.3.2\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 '
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='grep -E'
EXEEXT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS='-L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='Rcplex'
PACKAGE_STRING='Rcplex 0.3.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='rcplex'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.3.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC'
PKG_CPPFLAGS='-I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include'
PKG_LIBS='-L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
ac_ct_CC='clang'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host_alias=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Rcplex"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Rcplex 0.3.2"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "rcplex"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.3.2"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1

configure: exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `-L` for the lib directory rather than `-l`.

Try using the following:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC' 
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include 
PKG_LIBS='-L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic 
-lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'" Rcplex
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your comment, but it looks like you got further into the process than before. Can you update your question with the entire config.log using `-L`?

Comment: I substituted the old `config.log` with the new one. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the configuration step is now completing successfully. Before you deleted your comment, I think it said something about permissions issues. It would be helpful if you also shared the full error message you're getting in your question. You may be able to work around this by running the install command (in my answer) with `sudo`. For example, `sudo R CMD INSTALL ....`

Comment: Oh sorry, here's the new error output:
`Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) :
  problem copying ./NAMESPACE to /Users/andrews/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcplex/NAMESPACE: Permission denied
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file '/Users/andrews/Library/R/3.4/library/Rcplex/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘Rcplex’`

Comment: it worked with `sudo`! Thank you! so basically I can bypass permission errors with the `sudo` command. thanks a lot!